# How to change wp8 theme colors programmatically in c#

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to change overall windows phone 8  theme colors (both background & accent color) (Setting >> theme) programmatically from C# (xaml, html5 etc...) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only change the theme of your applicaition not the theme of Phone . you can detect phone theme as in this article : [Windows Phone Mango Custom application Theme Step by Step](http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/how-programmatically-detect)

but when you come to change it works only on your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response,  I wanted to write a wp8 app which also has the feature of changing the phone's theme bg/ accent color, which is not possible I believe 